# Non-BitTorrent way to get the Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

In order to avoid using/installing BitTorrent:

Do you know of any third party that has put the Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump(s) 7zip archive on their servers so that a direct download URL is available?

(At 200 MB it is within the same range of many podcasts and even more videocasts so the file size should not be a problem in itself — although of course content providers normally pay for it. But it could also be on another kind of server, such as for Open Source software or Creative Commons files).

Comment: What's wrong with using/installing BitTorrent? FUD?

Comment: Maybe corporate network policies?

Comment: Why would you legitimately need this data inside corporate network AND be unable to persuade IT to open BT for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments of the latest data dump, [Stu Thompson included a link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/creative-commons-data-dump-july-09/#comment-26995) to download the latest dump directly from his server:

http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/so-export-2009-07.tar.bz2

If you want a past dump, sth is hosting both the original dump and the SQLite version that I made on his server:

http://tejp.de/files/so-export/

Comment: All 3 links: 404

Answer (score 5):

A [list/directory of the Data Dumps](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/) (now broken) provided by Stu Thompson is available. And it is pony compliant too.

Note that, at the time of writing, the naming schemes differ. "October 2009 (SO/SF/SU)" equals "[Creative Commons Data Dump Nov 09](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-09/)" - though broken by now (all data up until 2009-11-01).

Thanks go to Stu Thompson for this great service.

Comment: Both links in your answer give 404 now.