# Is there a direct download link with a raw data dump of Stack Overflow? (not a torrent)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, downloads

I would like to create a local MySQL copy of Stack Overflow for academic purposes (school project). As far as I know, the database dump of the
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) database is available only in an XML format that I will have to convert to SQL on my own with some tool.

Most of direct download links I found were broken (404).
The only non-torrent source that I have found and that is still alive is http://tejp.de/files/so/dbdump/ but the latest Stack Overflow dump there is from October 2009, content of which looks like this:

[image]

***Where could I find a direct download link with the Stack Overflow dump?***

---

Note: I am not able to use torrents due to network policies, yet for the completeness of this question, here's the link that might help someone:  http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump

*Other related questions / links that haven't helped me:*

- [Can the Stack Exchange data dump be provided as a public data set on Amazon Web Services (AWS)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117178/178691)
- [Non-BitTorrent way to get the Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3764/178691) ~ all links there give 404
- [new data-dump in SQLite format available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21302/178691) ~ from September '09 with another broken link
- [Download Stack Overflow data for a research project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147908/178691) ~ from about a year ago with a clearbits.net link
- http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/ ~ also not working anymore

Comment: You really have no access to any network capable of torrent? Your home network? A $5 digitalocean instance? Anything?

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Let's just say it's complicated... for now I hope someone has uploaded somewhere a newer dump than the one from Oct '09 I mentioned

Comment: http://www.quick-torrent.com/

Comment: hi @LihO what method did you use to import the data into mysql? i am trying to do the same.

Comment: @ted.strauss: I guess what you actually want to use is: http://stackapps.com/questions/2511/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-for-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-and ...it's just a bit annoying that you have to specify path to folder that contains another folder named `SO` that contains the actual dump (xml files).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The latest Stack Exchange data dump with direct download links can be found [here at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

An older data dump (September 2013, uploaded by me to Mega) is below.

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://mega.co.nz/#!rFNR1Cba!OqtLVIlEwHtgKbr7OBza6NP0XT6uGmb_jON22HHiT8o) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!7Rsw1Y7A!7-a2lFR3fUnm8-R_J8gthNNQjjFgmauMRMVcXuEhJeE))
- [Ask Different](https://mega.co.nz/#!yYFhyIaB!paQQhy5M6C6qTmQRAVL3RDlH-v6h_K84VFs9bEDDQ7U) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!XMEByJRJ!kIFUjWduF6DsNsfS6oe-3hSUkjgBw38496oKqnNS18M))
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://mega.co.nz/#!qEMEgRyb!qEfWGB7SpVbpO9wD9XUmjjDsMIzZ__ZxStIXZCECXzw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!zEsGjK4S!Ja6dBu32rLRU2XUVmeASXwEOevbk2-GzSpeA0fSjZ6U))
- [Bicycles](https://mega.nz/#!CNdlDJIL!HCsn8y0ygqkFPXw2ntsLCiEJ5ZPz-ZF03jtDvVRxMD8) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!rENBWbJI!sjR66qtKyHrvD4nny72Ims7fDAAznPgEu0zo90s1k9w))
- [Christianity](https://mega.co.nz/#!rZE1TLZR!W_bqd52xy6DWaUm1pADeahkRlzkWzSEnAXPWcqKkVdw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!WYsQTJzR!dtQ4f3V5TJAJcoQDm_WCNEqJznQKYVssfuWJU3OK-NY))
- [Seasoned Advice](https://mega.co.nz/#!rV03BJzY!FIDEOj7n-aJpcdm2dpsIsL-TCsob-GsGJq9XdUmLrRU) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!mR0U2R5J!YmijFHcz_K5ddG-YyE62mvri-EXGYJeCzOA0kytAZ58))
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://mega.co.nz/#!KAkWxTRD!TFD1Otr6qdzqc_h_CnIX8a0V7NIXjQrcfuiqPb6dX8U) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!OZEjDZxA!li_c6rRQ0_wNxbbCgr5_YvfnosXtXgK0TelXMFCz5Oc))
- [Database Administrators](https://mega.co.nz/#!bFEnRBzQ!KE10a8Va19mjzCIUUEUgwFrRLA0F_tqE0z9nI1L4u7E) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!iBMngBhK!49xyqAIjP2hjLti8klK90HfZZJuXN4ZrC06VVv-vfz8))
- [Home Improvement](https://mega.co.nz/#!LcMDnL7T!IQ0jQXj3uMyZMxYkX-Lbj66TUDiFlvAPoro8hS3zADs) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!zcUTVQga!HFFXcY0LpVHvxl_O3MqncF7B79MA8T5fRyoYq10bPCo))
- [Drupal Answers](https://mega.co.nz/#!LNNgWQjB!Elc8cozpRyEcpN8Fa1FNsHj9LwgoQt1aQsDtbOdaHU0) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!iUUjGYrA!fj6NC64g0RqWJlaXrFlXJ0aRZiHzQts1lW6dJiBXnsQ))
- [Electrical Engineering](https://mega.nz/#!Od9iGBKA!orWokxQIyt6fQ9vYhY6V15JQTa5BKalP8WgOL1bNofU) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!bd1jgDpZ!UilukMEc0oCHU4Xle1TT_UMVVTXSI8teZYm8c7wtaYc))
- [English Language & Usage](https://mega.co.nz/#!LQ13jZCB!8pQRLj9TbcTcAczvcHPURaO8qtfMNyc4cQNIs8OiBzY) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!TBtFmaKD!ejgLdy0NlnERyDA76ybK4ofUKlI7BTfUNafPaNcWO2o))
- [Game Development](https://mega.nz/#!HFsSmRgS!sOmBg7ZBlYMXclZfwwrLrsHTcUEijBKSV2r6vgXttEw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!fF8H1ZzR!I_jCE6TXzrNekMKxUCosdvGN9CNBjINHtZXs3sEkO7Q))
- [Arqade](https://mega.co.nz/#!rFcFgbQI!6TmFAVF4TvKrsr1JMmgrGgq6yMCkHuBlR5CSSyEoORI) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!LQ9FXCxL!TDsMTTNgnuFbQvtYnGEHNXy-Eq7d_1NkSYtcqdapfbo))
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://mega.nz/#!zAUEACIS!o-JYBTeHFQYOXBlmf0BwJMUgh4PFZdY2pvm-kxnhToM) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!eEFAiChJ!wtxY5phmN5eKVEsCnOn6LD7IkPK8st4_VzYYDRbskQc))
- [Mi Yodeya](https://mega.nz/#!TcsAGYaZ!WZSJWlAqiBKTTpuRafdbMZ52cL78Z5nJOe4SqMdl2A4) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!SdtHHYSb!qeNP9Gq3fslJl3d5PB6rv1lX53AgrKyzscG26b8ytXM))
- [Mathematics](https://mega.co.nz/#!jENT0bYZ!9SDF1Q_ROy1T0aMWMq9hnexS_HWZlIeui2HqUg49R3k) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!3V9G2CaZ!wITOb5s25wVOb_4MUw2-KzNS6o4tPELhr2Tm0a06GmI))
- [Mathematica](https://mega.co.nz/#!aQsCQCaK!j6U9HRog4uWLPJJOEWJCGSuyq2QnBW8b_cC8lmec4c0) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!uFNhERJR!9Ipj_inVWiH15oVO1hQ2mtQWMJE-6eyWowaFfwAHZLk))
- [Math Overflow](https://mega.co.nz/#!zINhTYIY!lIPHlWREiZ_A3NlGDtvAg1B7gXdxVuFk0_NzdBm5mLU) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!vYEhHRAK!66TY7oVkM3_YEZsxsI9g7hFmkI8SXh-bmvP_I62aboc))
- [Photography](https://mega.co.nz/#!rcd0QYyS!hlSB0B-4XD0TqZyR9PiM4KOCWT1cEBHC1sTlf3XJyik) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!mAdCHYQS!JnTYKDcCsnYue38zgynS6n6tw-GjTvNKhp80DBXTxgY))
- [Physics](https://mega.nz/#!HNFnXYgB!42w1o_ZT6_SymIxid__fuI7A72vIlZxAXIjGSf2Vdm4) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!add3XBYJ!bZJnA-tA2iZlPwWb2AkTmbz-LlD8YTKdfJVhU1Pnjyc))
- [Programmers](https://mega.co.nz/#!Wc9H1IgL!Bj89sKgEbTcyEQV2xNE6MnvRsXJubmYNcGFid7A7IK4) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!WZ1QBIbD!6s9SloflComR_M5CmnIMySlyWIdHNeItVZovsq3mN3c))
- [Role-playing Games](https://mega.co.nz/#!zU8GXZaY!1re50eCqueGy2Hku2sfdiY6s9PAeCfUa3yT_p6FieZw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!LJMjUB7C!9xXWRMqaCOpAFYWLhdtysf22GxRxtgAeSTOMp8olnI0))
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://mega.nz/#!mdEFQBRb!EwyfnNRT9AImq7XFNxjB0mMrSlktHu0_pLJ240heggQ) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!vMNBHKZZ!fFEls4S6WMh0EB9htOTvAQ9OVEcz6p4yC1AVAJpiiVU))
- [Information Security](https://mega.co.nz/#!qd8ijSTJ!X7WCSewKGz31dumn1yXVswksRR-V_mlQJ3TcBRATj50) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!Wc93ESjB!NcKoOiKquTExfir5eDPL9HGhmbHejZdXLdoxrwP12w8))
- [Server Fault](https://mega.co.nz/#!uZsgmLpK!QWEySMe1EP10WOpYRZP5HdJKufyF7OGe1kr3jy3rFMY) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!nQlTwBDI!XhM_mkEDbgYTSElVbNXaKX9NFBsWYAHHF2shx3fheT0))
- [SharePoint](https://mega.co.nz/#!yZkzTZ7R!n6hRP8fHWFr4ynGbfSK-WMmjzT41WK_XFma30EtFCTY) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!mUUgUJhJ!aVfIC42v11xrpf4eVfYwLtRTjg0ArjlLOiLjKe-cQ0o))
- [Skeptics](https://mega.co.nz/#!zN1UhAQK!b1RhYP-DYQMvY77BByHANGP5IjK-GX4IyNuAeEm6qGU) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!LN8gELDD!_MYgp8hQPGJSMJ916U67ujadXeQsWlap33Y1v5T81ME))
- [Stack Apps](https://mega.nz/#!6ckEFBhK!_42sAx6no56uqBKL4RTeol54oJxlNeRX8LlN0UJfJ4U)
- Stack Overflow ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!jJ1T1SxZ!IDOl8zOtCXks1qKKOqw1ZJgkmdhTkUOiXOyXr8v7BQQ))

  - [Part 1](https://mega.co.nz/#!vNlCgDpY!j9DECnh1_V2OO24UTp1HLN--u6lm_gtg9JvfL02iNCI)
  - [Part 2](https://mega.co.nz/#!qVUVnSDS!efx1UUJhP2tWBp1CfUyLeQ_6IoMfZWdgPyfbSqkFaf4)
  - [Part 3](https://mega.nz/#!uQtiCY6L!luQBIeWODdliAjpPG7-IBZhuyjm1vujByMZcuzRrmrI)
  - [Part 4](https://mega.nz/#!eU1QTRab!yQPLrsfEZkrty6iJYDT69YvqiniM1kxsUcndHRb7meU)
  - [Part 5](https://mega.co.nz/#!vRNFiAJa!aGQyZ-Eu47-JMg7uAYdtxaB9UWNcUT5elNZJldUN5fw)
  - [Part 6](https://mega.co.nz/#!TZ1SRbgQ!ZZo_nO563MghikIss7aAePCmTjzSyDh0L2WefW37Pog)
  - [Part 7](https://mega.nz/#!KBdkzKYT!E1TEOwoDEM7AL4OwWFVfvxb6jvRNvBtaY8LM_qoY1M4)
  - [Part 8](https://mega.co.nz/#!rBcEFJyA!P9OL-37CRjdrambYa12gFbb_YLjjzf__coUtixvMoNk)
  - [Part 9](https://mega.co.nz/#!yZdCETQR!uwa-LFv6aQtIsMjcIw_Ww0QIZCXUf5myzMMEsJnQYn0)
  - [Part 10](https://mega.nz/#!7BVD1ABY!veN3-LaJBRkcX9VxkNAtPGvsz1ltDawzuk8uk_S_wDc)
  - [Part 11](https://mega.co.nz/#!TNl0zb7J!JaK2kjHy9oid-PpKnMrTGO0nU766jk8d9tZBA7SLWwo)
  - [Part 12](https://mega.co.nz/#!WQ9QSTjT!C7lgTWpAy3huf3HnRHiWaGRfTl8Vj1t8wt8vAg06CSc)
  - [Part 13](https://mega.nz/#!2UlWmQzJ!3o3Ekc8AZIw3AnMW0S4UBfVctDhsNOvdn8vCkevkcqM)
  - [Part 14](https://mega.co.nz/#!zJci1RTa!wys74tXWm-JWKupiYH9l92CIy1aOkaUixV8HFfLkIGc)
  - [Part 15](https://mega.co.nz/#!PFNEHaYb!FvAWNKjH9zk5-fTMT9n2VlSLswVEDnO-kATnTBJ88o8)
  - [Part 16](https://mega.co.nz/#!eJNxES7a!xgZ8JADVaipLcDSkCJUAA9RBceBrkwEiwLXtH8LHers)
  - [Part 17](https://mega.co.nz/#!6AEwGKKB!BZ6GXI4WSy2ExshEE-3ALT1mxylRnVM3cb46a-alo3A)
  - [Part 18](https://mega.co.nz/#!SEFhGJCZ!cKTJNnsBM78ZBXUuRDnG-76Ef2eWDAymNQtTH3-TG8o)
- [Cross Validated](https://mega.nz/#!PFFRGIpK!ASmnODyuztpz9BJQ9CEIPK73sBNeZw3Epjr_-10G4sc) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!TclHBAjS!QtFRTWEQWaVXXScOIG7HzBtH3eBklXtOUdivVGbToxs))
- [Super User](https://mega.co.nz/#!iNFXFaaC!HSwsCAZI89_7MxaId4sAeG29Bm-y0hhtI8N1QzD1ppA) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!eINRSBxL!wZbFO5VxX7-v8nd06z7OW4YEzprpZzlTqNvFqHJvjiE))
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://mega.co.nz/#!rFVQzaIS!0C-thXeIy3LSBM3NuoXUhV12trQ1Blaw9D8YuTlW63k) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!eZkFUAQb!NqxwUwig07vR3vQCn6GxrzssGlFOZsv4y1_bQ4gjwYI))
- [Travel](https://mega.co.nz/#!ndcVHLKC!MHEL80dvh9sHi-dM_h6a_JqdrXyw83vxExwbzHSML7A) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!LN8BgKwC!ZPGfrR2wahk-e5-1zOo7MIvGneHAkYQLS4ncsNsFv7k))
- [Unix & Linux](https://mega.co.nz/#!LJsCWLqb!EKr4ux5vORyQshDdK732JlROk2lcoiWITLDObGwWVkw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!udUyDbRK!l23iJeS5JXQ2iTv7w9qHL7oN2BW0qahJX2vy_5Ucc04))
- [User Experience](https://mega.co.nz/#!PMMRSBBL!uxDyUhzxAR_qlcGigwO-yQrKaxjt7t0ns1I3BaY9kag) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!WRtgkLIR!SwWx5-m6tkuQ4i9PGDBGcVYzKd6lXJFH5p_GtdbD-Ao))
- [Web Applications](https://mega.co.nz/#!KEdByA4T!Xd60pa0uSB26k_HTCdxOdW9yRf2GJQ5quYmb1YXfiQk) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!XBtyUYDD!BE0o9LvRda0IvKCsnt9BW8-E9kt95jVd3FPbnCabJkc))
- [Webmasters](https://mega.nz/#!aFshUIDY!TnpzA_mYA_fM5FhTpuArDJA5nccz65ImCnMTG8tqOE0) ([Meta](https://mega.nz/#!DQkDHCJR!P4VIMrBMyzox-0gW_1Tza47Cemwm58xxHyk7s_cUE_g))
- [WordPress Answers](https://mega.co.nz/#!mZExDBKZ!Ne6Z6a3IW9PC2983eq-DjVbEdl1xTBZ_DfZpEUC2BHw) ([Meta](https://mega.co.nz/#!aZ1yWLSA!XbRGQAtOVsxWAeyg0V5hmlkj8yHmYabyRJB23vLiZuU))

Regarding the dumps being "anonymized", [please see this question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193802/does-the-public-data-dump-contain-user-names-or-not) for details. In short: no votes, no personal data.

Comment: (JDownloader is useful to download many of those links at once.)

Comment: Are older dumps available through Archive.org? I couldn't find any.

Comment: @romkyns I guess there are no official older dumps, but you could take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922) that lists magnet links for older dumps. I don't know if the links are alive, but you can try.

Comment: how do you take these xml files and turn them into mysql files?

Comment: The dumps don't contain images. Images can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/Stack-Exchange-Image-Dataset).