# Data Dump Vs. API

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, api, archive

I was looking around the API and felt guilty in setting up a nasty code in order to build a datadump. Just to check before doing it, there is no Stack archives available ? something like githubarchive.org for github API ?
Since my purpose is more an analysis of Stack than building an app, I need more all static data, than access to the freshest dynamic one.
thanks,
Antoine

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198915/is-there-a-direct-download-link-with-a-raw-data-dump-of-stack-overflow-not-a-t

Comment: You added the "data-dump" tag to your question: doesn't the fact that the tag exists sort of answer your question? Couldn't you have checked what other questions have the tag?

Comment: Thanks Oded, exactly this ! David, I **of course** looked around before asking. Seems that google or even *related* proposals from stack didn't match any of Oded's pertinent answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is not the right tool for this.

We have had public data dumps going out for years.

At this time, we create a 7z file containing all the public data.

The latest official data dump on Archive.org is from [September 2018](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange).